# SQL Developer - default open specific tables after connection

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

does anyone know how to set up default "seeing" of specific tables after connecting to the DB? E.g. we have tables A,B,C,D and after connecting to the DB I want to see TAB with table A and TAB with table B.

Thank you

[image]

Comment: you can open a table view and then click on a read pin, when you open the next table view it will be opend in a new tab

Comment: Hi hotfix, it is not what I wanted. This can be set in the settings general for all tables. I mean if you would close Oracle developer and open again, I ´d like to see already those tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this isn't possible today in Oracle SQL Developer.

You could submit an enhancement request to My Oracle Support or put in an idea to sqldeveloper.oracle.com